# How to do Continuous Integration with a live website without affecting users?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, continuous-integration

I have implemented Continuous Integration using TFS Version Control and TFS Build 2010.  The compiled website project gets dropped in a shared folder with a version number.

Now I have a very basic question and may be a stupid question.  When we normally deploy a website project from VS 2010 to a webserver it uploads App_Offline.htm file to the website folder so no requests are served to the user.  After publish is completed that App_Offline.htm file is removed.  During that period of time users see outage.

If we use CI on a live website then how can we eliminate that outage which appears to a user.  I believe the whole point of CI is that users get to see newer features and the site is never down.

How is this accomplished? If we deploy website project to root folder then existing users will be affected and that is certainly no advisable.

I wanted to know what is the recommended practice with VS2010, TFS2010 Build & Version Control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no real foolproof method for this, service up-time is never 100%, that's why people usually define it in '[nines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_availability#Percentage_calculation)'

But, if you had multiple web servers (Backup, fail-over, mirror etc.), you could roll out the update across them, so that as you update some servers, others will still be online (albeit with the old version) to serve users.

In general, only some of the largest websites have to worry so meticulously about being down for a few short minutes, so make sure you're focusing your energy in the right place ; )

Answer (score 1):

Regarding taking down the site for the shortest time possible, the only way I've seen this done successfully is using multiple sites - either load balancing, or 2 sites on the same machine + swapping host headers after the release/warm up.  But in most cases it's not worth the effort, releases shouldn't take down the site for more than a few seconds in which time there should be relatively few requests.  You're better off trying a few things you can do to help your users live through a site release.

**Move session out of proc.** 
If the users session lives in the app pool it will be lost when a new version is released, change the config to move it into a session server or the database.

**Specify a machine key for the website**
Viewstate (and cookies?) are encrypted using a key that is generated when a site starts, if a site restarts due to a release any users filling out a form will receive a invalid viewstate exception on postback.  (Note: this may have other security implications)